# Retrieve errors from MySQLDataAdapter.update()

Tags: vb.net, mysql-connector

I'm deliberately trying to change my dataset to have a duplicate primary key with the expectation that this action would throw a mysql error.

How can I retrieve such errors from `MySQLDataAdapter.Update()`??

I've had a brief look at event handlers but I can't seem to find where to get the error anywhere. Although I did notice that `MySqlRowUpdatingEventArgs.Status = SkipCurrentRow`

Code snippet:

```
Private Sub UpdateTable()
    Dim MyCommandBuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder(MyDataadapter)
    txtConsole.AppendText(vbNewLine & MyDataSet.HasErrors.ToString)

    AddHandler MyDataadapter.RowUpdating, AddressOf OnRowUpdating
    AddHandler MyDataadapter.RowUpdated, AddressOf OnRowUpdated

    If MyDataSet.GetChanges() Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("The table contains no changes to save.")
    Else
        ' Without the MySqlCommandBuilder this line would fail.
        Try
            Dim rowsAffected As Integer = MyDataadapter.Update(MyDataTable)
            If rowsAffected = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No rows were affected by the save operation.")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected & " rows were affected by the save operation.")
            End If
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            txtConsole.AppendText(vbNewLine & "Error: " & ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End If

    RemoveHandler MyDataadapter.RowUpdating, AddressOf OnRowUpdating
    RemoveHandler MyDataadapter.RowUpdated, AddressOf OnRowUpdated

End Sub

' handler for RowUpdating event 
Private Shared Sub OnRowUpdating(sender As Object, e As MySqlRowUpdatingEventArgs)
    PrintEventArgs(e)
End Sub

' handler for RowUpdated event 
Private Shared Sub OnRowUpdated(sender As Object, e As MySqlRowUpdatedEventArgs)
    PrintEventArgs(e)
End Sub


Private Overloads Shared Sub PrintEventArgs(args As MySqlRowUpdatingEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("OnRowUpdating")
    Console.WriteLine("  event args: (" & " command=" & args.Command.CommandText & _
       " commandType=" & args.StatementType & " status=" & args.Status & ")")
End Sub


Private Overloads Shared Sub PrintEventArgs(args As MySqlRowUpdatedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("OnRowUpdated")
    Console.WriteLine("  event args: (" & " command=" & args.Command.CommandText & _
       " commandType=" & args.StatementType & " recordsAffected=" & _
       args.RecordsAffected & " status=" & args.Status & ")")
End Sub
```

Comment: look in `ex.Message`?

Comment: @safetyOtter Unfortunately it's not throwing an exception.

Comment: is the update happening?

Comment: @safetyOtter Yes everything works fine even the row in question updates except for the pk of course but I hadn't noticed it was still updating the rest of the fields in the row so it is obviously handled by `MySQLDataAdapter`